# Internet radio server bandwidth usage

Tags: bandwidth, internet-radio

I want to setup an internet radio server, taking into account a number of constraints.

Lets ignore for now the non-IT related issues, like legal/organizational aspects.

I need to calculate how the required server bandwidth will be influenced, in the following cases:

1. Up to 10’000 simultaneous listeners
2. Impact of the geographical distribution of clients(in the same city/same country/worldwide)
3. Sound quality options each person will be able to choose from(low/high quality); will more quality options augment the required bandwidth?
4. Are there any other important factors going to influence the server bandwidth usage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the only factor that truly influences the bandwidth usage is the number of listeners and the quality at which they choose to connect.

More important will be the maximum number of simultaneous listeners that needs to be supported, as that, multiplied by the mean bandwidth used per listener, will give the maximum throughput that the server connection will need to support.

Apparently, the geographical distribution of the listeners will neither increase nor help decrease these numbers.